# jQuery's .append() : strange behavior

Tags: jquery, dom, append

I face a strange behavior with the [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) method of jQuery.

```
var container = $('#container');


var buttons = {
    'Okay': function() {
        return 'Yeah, I\'m okay with this.';
    },
    'Nope': function() {
        return 'No, no, definitively no.';
    },
    'Maybe': function() {
        return 'Hum, maybe.';
    }
};


for(var button_label in buttons) {
    var button_callback = buttons[button_label];

    var button_html = $('<button type="button">' + button_label + '</button>');

    button_html.on('click', function() {
        alert('button : ' + $(this).text() + ', callback : ' + button_callback());
    });

    container.append(button_html);
}
```

[View the code on JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/EdohACE/1/)

All is working fine, except, as you can see, when clicking on all buttons : the same callback is called (the last defined in the `buttons` object). I checked the jQuery's doc, and maybe this is related :

> If there is more than one target element, however, cloned copies of the inserted element will be created for each target after the first.

Or, I need to refactor my code. I tested different solutions, but none worked. Anyone can help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the good old "variable in a loop passed to a callback" issue which exists here on Stack Overflow a billion times. So it's not related to jQuery at all.

What you need to do is create a new variable during each loop. The easiest way to do so is using an anonymous function that's executed immediately and receives the value as a parameter.

```
(function(button_callback) {
    button_html.on('click', function() {
        alert('button : ' + $(this).text() + ', callback : ' + button_callback());
    });
})(button_callback);
```

[Updated JSBin](http://jsbin.com/EdohACE/8/edit)

Why is this necessary? In JavaScript there is no block scope. Only functions create a new scope. So in your original code `var button_callback` is hoisted to the top of the scope (the function containing your loop or the global scope if there's none). So in each iteration you have the *same* variable. And this variable is bound to the closure of your anonymous function. So after the loop the variable has the last value - in all three functions.

Comment: You can add nice article about IIFE like this one : http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/

Comment: Thanks Thief for your detailed answer (even if it's a noob question, I'm not using JS every day), and thanks for the dude who answered me thinking I'm a total SO no-life knowing every community rules through and through.